# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Spring Boot

Tags: java, android, spring

I'm creating an eductional system for learning through games and I'm using android as a front-end and Spring boot as a back-end and I'm creating a service for creating a course and I take the data from the front end through this link `http://localhost:8090/addcourse/{teacherID}`
but when I run the program it gives me an error and I don't know ho to solve it

**Error Message:** Error resolving template "addcourse/2", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

**Service:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addcourse/{teacherId}")
public Map<String,String> createCourse(@RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable int teacherId) {
    Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
    User  Teacher = userRep.findOne(teacherId);
    if(Teacher.getTeacherCode()=="TA123") {
        course.setUser(Teacher);
        courseRep.save(course);
        data.put("check", "true");
        Course course2 = courseRep.findByCourseName(course.getCourseName());
        data.put("ID", course2.getCourseID()+"");
        return data;
    }

    data.put("check", "false");
    return data;
}
```

Comment: please edit you question. look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `Map` from your controller which does not give Spring MVC a hint which view name it should use. So it deduces it from the URL used to access the controller, in this case it's `addcourse/2`. Probably you don't have a view (a Thymeleaf template) per teacher; I suppose that you have a Thymeleaf view called `addcourse`.

Try returning view name explicitly:

```
return new ModelAndView("addcourse", data);
```

instead of

```
return data;
```

`"addcourse"` has to be changed to your real template name.